# Node.js npm install pg-sync error

Tags: node.js, installation, pg

I would install pg-sync for Node.js, but it shows this error:

```
peter@loki ~/node $ npm install pg-sync

> pg-sync@0.1.0 install /home/peter/node/node_modules/pg-sync
> node-gyp rebuild || (exit 0)

make: Entering directory `/home/peter/node/node_modules/pg-sync/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/pgsync/src/pgsync.o
../src/pgsync.cc:14:1: error: overloaded function with no contextual type information
make: *** [Release/obj.target/pgsync/src/pgsync.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/home/peter/node/node_modules/pg-sync/build'
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/lib64/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:809:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.4-gentoo
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/lib64/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/peter/node/node_modules/pg-sync
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.29
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.13.1
gyp ERR! not ok
pg-sync@0.1.0 node_modules/pg-sync
└── nan@0.8.0
```

How can I fix this? I have test remove the .node_gyp and update nodejs to actual version, but it shows the same error.
**Edit**
Bug is fixed, show this: [Issue #1 Github](https://github.com/RayKitajima/pg-sync/issues/1)

Comment: You could try using the node-postgres module instead. It has bindings to the native libpq library, and has worked well in my experience.